# CSS: Set popup width based on buttons width and not message width

Tags: css, popup, word-wrap

I have a "popup window" that looks like this :
[image: popup]

As you can see, the width of the popup extends with the text width.

**What I'm trying to get is the text width to be bounded by the width of the container containing the two buttons.**

**UPDATE:** here is what I want:

[image]

**The loooong text should still be entirely displayed**, but it should then continue on the next line.

This sounds pretty easy in theory but I tried tons of different things, and I haven't been able to solve this (I am looking for a pure CSS solution).

Structure of this popup:

```
<div class="popup">
    <div class="msg">Very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooon text</div>
    <div class="buttons-container">
        <div class="button">Button number one</div>
        <div class="button">Button number two</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And base css (the popup needs a position absolute):

```
.popup {
border: solid 1px red;
position: absolute;
}
.msg {
}
.buttons-container {
clear: both;
}
.button {
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px 10px;
background-color: darkGray;
}
```

- [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5B7v/)

Comment: I guess Without a fixed `width` ?

Comment: Absolutely, the text for the buttons and the message is not fixed.

Comment: Maybe center the buttons and set a max-width on the popup: http://jsfiddle.net/A5B7v/3/

Comment: @DavidAlsbright that's probably more sensible than my hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

table, or display:flex to use buttons inherit size. absolute position to set the size for text label.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/9QkEa/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="label">
        <span>ssssss ssssssss ssssssss sssss</span>
    </div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><button>leftttttttttttttttt</button></td><td><button>right</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

style:

```
#container {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#label {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#label span {
    position: absolute;
}
```

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/9QkEa/3/

Trick here is to use a visibility:hidden button group inside a display:flex to set the size. You can probably get it to work with table too.

Then use `positive:relative`, `position:absolute`, and `align-items:strech`, to create a container of correct width but auto height.

However, it is using overflow. so the outer most container needs to allow overflow, and might be tricky to position.

This is hacky and if you have better options (JavaScript, Wink Wink) use that.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="label">
        <span>xssss as dasd asd as dasd asdas dsad asd asd adada sd asd</span>
        <div class="button-container">
            <button>leftttttttttttttttt</button><button>right</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hidden" class="button-container">
        <button>leftttttttttttttttt</button><button>right</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

style

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;    
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#label {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: grey;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.button-container {
    padding: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I need the text to be fully visible still (cf this: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wum0.png) )